# Invalid data source source type. The data source must be of type IListSource, IEnumerable or IDataSource

Tags: ext.net

I am prety new on MVC app.my problem is that vs gives me an error something like this.
"Invalid data source source type. The data source must be of type IListSource, IEnumerable or IDataSource."

**what I wanna do in this senario is [using this sample](http://mvc.ext.net/#/DataView_Basic/Paging/) making pagination with my entitiy.
here is the my view

```
    @(
 Html.X().Panel()
            .ID("ImagePanel")
            .Cls("images-view")
            .Frame(true)
            .Width(535)
            .Collapsible(true)
            .Title("URUNLER")
            .Items(
                Html.X().DataView()
                    .ID("ImageView")
                    .Store(
                        Html.X().Store()
                            .RemotePaging(true)
                            .AutoLoad(false)
                            .ID("Store1")
                            .PageSize(5)
                            .DataSource(Model)

                            .Model(
                                Html.X().Model()
                            .IDProperty("ID")
                            .Fields(
                             Html.X().ModelField().Name("Ad"),
                             Html.X().ModelField().Name("Aciklama")

                                    )
                            )
                                .Proxy(Html.X().AjaxProxy()
                                .Url(Url.Action("Read"))
                                .Reader(Html.X().JsonReader().Root("data").TotalProperty("data.TotalRecords"))

              )
            )

           .EmptyText("")
           .TrackOver(true)
          .Tpl(
       Html.X().XTemplate()
      .Html(
       @<text>
        <tpl for=".">
       <div class="thumb-wrap" id="{Ad}">
       <div class="thumb"><img src="{Ad}" title="{Ad}"></div>
       <span class="x-editable">{Aciklama}</span>
       </div>
      </tpl>
        <div class="x-clear"></div>
        </text>
                            )
                    )


            )
            .BottomBar(
                Html.X().PagingToolbar().StoreID("Store1").HideRefresh(true)
            )
    )
```

and my controlerr

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Read(StoreRequestParameters parameters)
        {
            int TotalRecords;
            int start = parameters.Start;
            int limit = parameters.Limit;
            string sort = "1";
            return this.Store(PlantsPaging(start, limit, sort, out TotalRecords));
        }



        public Paging<Urun> PlantsPaging(int start, int limit, string sort, out int TotalRecords)
        {
            Urun_BLL urun_bll = new Urun_BLL();
            var data = urun_bll.Getir(start, limit, sort, out TotalRecords);

            return new Paging<Urun>(data, TotalRecords);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading the data via an AjaxProxy and are not passing any Model to the View, you should remove this:

```
.DataSource(Model)
```

At runtime it is:

```
.DataSource(null)
```

And yes, it throws an exception, because it is not something that a Store's DataSource expects.

Comment: thank you daniil for response.it seems it works but now "Read action result" seems not working when page loading.I just only can see the dataview skeleton without data

Comment: Please post a response of the Read action.

Comment: daniil I solve the problem ,it was my mistake.thank you for your help again